# String formatting using LINQ2SQL

Tags: c#, asp.net, string

I have a TextBox (which shows notes). Now the user Selects his/her name and then ADD the note.
I want to show that note in the RIGHT Hand side of that page so that they can review his/her and past notes. My Table contains these items:

> Memo
>   DateCreated
>   User

This code here:

```
  var showMemo = from r in em.EntityMemoVs_1s
                      where r.EntityID == getEntity
                      select r.Memo;
  var showUser = from r in em.EntityMemoVs_1s
                      where r.EntityID == getEntity
                      select r.User;
tbShowNote.Text = String.Join(Environment.NewLine, showMemo);
tbShowNote.Text += String.Join(Environment.NewLine, showUser);
```

This is showing me notes in this fashion:

> Test1
>   Test2 
>   Test3 User1 User2 User3

I dont want this way...I want something like this:

> 5/5/2011: This is first note. -User1
>   5/6/2011: This is second note. -User2

How should I achieve this? Thanks!

Comment: Isn't this the same as your previous question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5954889/showing-notes-using-string-join

Comment: @BrokenGlass - I concur. The end result is slightly different, but the principle is the same.

Comment: form which field you extract date?

Comment: Why not use a gridview or listview?

Comment: @BrokenGlass: Some of the items changed...as compared to my previous post...

Comment: @Chad: Just a notepad kind of thing is okay....Nothing too complicated..

Comment: @Serghei: Its a column in my DB DateCreated. I am not pulling it now..But I wanna show it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, if you want everything inline, you could do:

```
 var notes = from r in em.EntityMemoVs_1s
                      where r.EntityID == getEntity
                      select r.CreatedDate.ToShortDateString() + ": " + 
                      r.Memo + " - " + r.User;
txtShowNote.Text = String.Join("<br/>", notes);
```

Essentially, create the string in the LINQ query as one statement, and if you are posting to the web, use `<br/>` instead of New lines.

HTH.

Comment: Tried using the Environment.NewLine. It worked!